# Troubleshooting stored procedures "sometimes" slow performance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have some stored procedures with performance that varies widely. I don't know why.

An example is stored procedure 1 usually takes less than 1 sec but can sometimes take 28 secs! We are looking at the same SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition, same stored procedure, same database, same amount of data. I am lost trying to figure out what is going on.

Any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

Wide gaps:

```
min_physical_reads  max_physical_reads
518 6833

min_worker_time max_worker_time
93011   310917

min_logical_writes  max_logical_writes
0   173

min_elapsed_time    max_elapsed_time
158005  27479580
```

Here are the stats from DMV

```
cached_time
2014-09-11 19:00:03.267
cached_time last_execution_time execution_count total_worker_time   last_worker_time    min_worker_time max_worker_time total_physical_reads    last_physical_reads min_physical_reads  max_physical_reads  total_logical_writes    last_logical_writes min_logical_writes  max_logical_writes  total_logical_reads last_logical_reads  min_logical_reads   max_logical_reads   total_elapsed_time  last_elapsed_time   min_elapsed_time    max_elapsed_time
2014-09-11 19:00:03.267 2014-09-12 13:04:13.097 18  2194087 113974  93011   310917  20715   518 518 6833    2439    169 0

    173 863985  47981   47981   48145   65239761    237022  158005  27479580
```

SPROC

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetFormularyProducts]
    @formularyType tinyint, -- 1 Practice   2 OSC
    @PracticeID int = NULL,
    @Filter int = 0,            -- 0- Assigned  1-Practice Owned 2-Show All  3 - Show All for IsPractice
    @PageSize int = -1,
    @CurrentPage int = -1,
    @TenantID int
AS

SET NOCOUNT ON
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
/*** Log the start of the stored procedure ***/
DECLARE
    @ProcLog_ProcName varchar(256),
    @ProcLog_ParamList varchar(max),
    @ProcLog_ProcLogID bigint,
    @ProcLog_LogCompletion bit

SET @ProcLog_ProcName = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.NucleusVariables WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE VariableName = 'Log' + @ProcLog_ProcName AND VariableValue = '1')
BEGIN
    SET @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
    SET @ProcLog_ParamList = ' @FormularyType = ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(15), @FormularyType), 'NULL') + 
                              ' @PracticeID = ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(15), @PracticeID), 'NULL') + 
                              ' @Filter = ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(15), @Filter), 'NULL') + 
                              ' @PageSize = ' + ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(15), @PageSize), 'NULL')  

    EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ParamList = @ProcLog_ParamList, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID OUTPUT
END
/*********************************************/
IF @formularyType = 1
BEGIN
    IF @Filter = 0   -- Assigned within this Practice
    BEGIN
        SELECT DISTINCT P.ProductKey
        INTO #ProdKey
        FROM dbo.Product P
            INNER JOIN dbo.Inventory I ON P.ProductKey = I.ProductKey
        WHERE P.PracticeID = @PracticeID

        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PROD.[Name] ASC) AS rownum,
            PROD.ProductKey,
            PROD.TypeKey,
            PROD.TradeName,
            PROD.Active,
            PV.[Current] as ActiveVendor,
            PROD.[Name],
            PROD.GenericName,
            PROD.[Name] + char(10) + char(13) + dbo.fn_BuildGenericName(PROD.genericname,
            T.TypeName,
            PROD.RefrigeratedItem,
            PROD.Punitsize,
            PROD.DConversionfactor,
            UOMDU.Display) AS VirtualNameCRGenericName,
            PROD.NDC,
            PROD.ItemID,
            IsNull(PROD.ItemID, '''') + char(10) + char(13) + IsNull(PROD.NDC, '''') AS VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
            PROD.OncologyOwned,
            DerivedProduct,
            PROD.Discontinued AS DiscontinuedProduct,
            PROD.SequenceNumber,
            PROD.IsAuditFavorite,
            PROD.GCN,
            PROD.DrugGenericName,
            PROD.GPI
        INTO #GetFormularyProduct4
        FROM dbo.Product PROD
            INNER JOIN #ProdKey PK ON PK.ProductKey = PROD.ProductKey
            INNER JOIN dbo.TypeLookup T ON T.TypeId = PROD.TypeKey
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ProductVendor PV ON PV.ProductKey = PROD.ProductKey
                AND PV.[Current] = 'true'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasureCode UOMDU ON UOMDU.UOMKey = PROD.DUOMKey
        WHERE PROD.Active = 'True'
            AND PROD.TypeKey <> 129
            AND PROD.PracticeID = @PracticeID
        ORDER BY PROD.[Name]


        IF @PageSize = -1 OR @CurrentPage = -1
        BEGIN
            SELECT rownum,
                ProductKey,
                TypeKey,
                TradeName,
                Active,
                ActiveVendor,
                [Name],
                GenericName,
                VirtualNameCRGenericName,
                NDC,
                ItemID,
                VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
                OncologyOwned,
                DerivedProduct,
                DiscontinuedProduct,
                SequenceNumber,
                IsAuditFavorite,
                GCN,
                DrugGenericName,
                GPI
            FROM #GetFormularyProduct4
            ORDER BY [Name]

                /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/
            RETURN (0)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_uc_rownum4 ON #GetFormularyProduct4 (rownum)

            SELECT rownum,
                ProductKey,
                TypeKey,
                TradeName,
                Active,
                ActiveVendor,
                [Name],
                GenericName,
                VirtualNameCRGenericName,
                NDC,
                ItemID,
                VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
                OncologyOwned,
                DerivedProduct,
                DiscontinuedProduct,
                SequenceNumber,
                IsAuditFavorite,
                GCN,
                DrugGenericName,
                GPI
            FROM #GetFormularyProduct4
            WHERE rownum BETWEEN (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @CurrentPage * @PageSize
            ORDER BY [Name]

              /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/

            RETURN (0)
        END
    END



    IF @Filter = 1   --Practice Owned
    BEGIN
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PROD.[Name] ASC) AS rownum,
            PROD.ProductKey,
            PROD.TypeKey,
            PROD.TradeName,
            PROD.Active,
            PV.[Current] as ActiveVendor,
            PROD.[Name],
            PROD.GenericName,
            PROD.[Name] + char(10) + char(13) + dbo.fn_BuildGenericName(PROD.genericname,
            T.TypeName,
            PROD.RefrigeratedItem,
            PROD.Punitsize,
            PROD.DConversionfactor,
            UOMDU.Display) AS VirtualNameCRGenericName,
            PROD.NDC,
            PROD.ItemID,
            IsNull(PROD.ItemID, '''') + char(10) + char(13) + IsNull(PROD.NDC, '''') AS VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
            PROD.OncologyOwned,
            DerivedProduct,
            PROD.Discontinued AS DiscontinuedProduct,
            PROD.SequenceNumber,
            PROD.IsAuditFavorite,
            PROD.GCN,
            PROD.DrugGenericName,
            PROD.GPI
        INTO #GetFormularyProduct1
        FROM dbo.Product PROD
            INNER JOIN dbo.TypeLookup T ON T.TypeId = PROD.TypeKey
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ProductVendor PV ON PV.ProductKey = PROD.ProductKey
                AND PV.[Current] = 'true'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasureCode UOMDU ON UOMDU.UOMKey = PROD.DUOMKey
        WHERE PROD.Active = 'True'
            AND PROD.TypeKey <> 129
            AND PROD.PracticeID = @PracticeID
            AND PROD.DerivedProduct IS NULL
        ORDER BY PROD.[Name]


        IF @PageSize = -1 OR @CurrentPage = -1
        BEGIN
            SELECT rownum,
                ProductKey,
                TypeKey,
                TradeName,
                Active,
                ActiveVendor,
                [Name],
                GenericName,
                VirtualNameCRGenericName,
                NDC,
                ItemID,
                VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
                OncologyOwned,
                DerivedProduct,
                DiscontinuedProduct,
                SequenceNumber,
                IsAuditFavorite,
                GCN,
                DrugGenericName,
                GPI
            FROM #GetFormularyProduct1
            ORDER BY [Name]

              /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/

            RETURN (0)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_uc_rownum1 ON #GetFormularyProduct1 (rownum)

            SELECT rownum,
            ProductKey,
            TypeKey,
            TradeName,
            Active,
            ActiveVendor,
            [Name],
            GenericName,
            VirtualNameCRGenericName,
            NDC,
            ItemID,
            VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
            OncologyOwned,
            DerivedProduct,
            DiscontinuedProduct,
            SequenceNumber,
            IsAuditFavorite,
            GCN,
            DrugGenericName,
            GPI
            FROM #GetFormularyProduct1
            WHERE rownum BETWEEN (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @CurrentPage * @PageSize
            ORDER BY [Name]

              /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/

            RETURN (0)
        END

    END
    ELSE



    IF @Filter = 2  --Show All
    BEGIN

        CREATE TABLE #DiscontinuedAndNotAssigned (ProductKey int NOT NULL)

        --These discontinued products are NOT assigned anywhere within this practice; we can remove them from the list
        INSERT INTO #DiscontinuedAndNotAssigned (ProductKey)
        SELECT DISTINCT P.ProductKey
        FROM dbo.Product P
        WHERE P.PracticeID = @PracticeID
            AND P.Discontinued = 1
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Inventory I WHERE I.ProductKey = P.ProductKey AND I.Active = 1)

        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PROD.[Name] ASC) AS rownum,
            PROD.ProductKey,
            PROD.TypeKey,
            PROD.TradeName,
            PROD.Active,
            PV.[Current] AS ActiveVendor,
            PROD.[Name],
            PROD.GenericName,
            PROD.[Name] + char(10) + char(13)
            + dbo.fn_BuildGenericName(PROD.genericname, T.TypeName, PROD.RefrigeratedItem, PROD.Punitsize, PROD.DConversionfactor, UOMDU.Display) AS VirtualNameCRGenericName,
            PROD.NDC,
            PROD.ItemID,
            ISNULL(PROD.ItemID, '''') + char(10) + char(13) + ISNULL(PROD.NDC, '''') AS VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
            PROD.OncologyOwned,
            DerivedProduct,
            PROD.Discontinued AS DiscontinuedProduct,
            PROD.SequenceNumber,
            PROD.IsAuditFavorite,
            PROD.GCN,
            PROD.DrugGenericName,
            PROD.GPI
        INTO #GetFormularyProduct3
        FROM dbo.Product PROD
            INNER JOIN dbo.TypeLookup T ON T.TypeId = PROD.TypeKey
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ProductVendor PV ON PV.ProductKey = PROD.ProductKey
                AND PV.[Current] = 'true'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasureCode UOMDU ON UOMDU.UOMKey = PROD.DUOMKey
        WHERE PROD.Active = 'True'
            AND PROD.TypeKey <> 129
            AND PROD.PracticeID = @PracticeID
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ProductKey FROM #DiscontinuedAndNotAssigned X WHERE X.ProductKey = PROD.ProductKey)
        ORDER BY PROD.[Name]


        IF @PageSize = -1 OR @CurrentPage = -1
        BEGIN
            SELECT rownum,
                ProductKey,
                TypeKey,
                TradeName,
                Active,
                ActiveVendor,
                [Name],
                GenericName,
                VirtualNameCRGenericName,
                NDC,
                ItemID,
                VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
                OncologyOwned,
                DerivedProduct,
                DiscontinuedProduct,
                SequenceNumber,
                IsAuditFavorite,
                GCN,
                DrugGenericName,
                GPI
            FROM #GetFormularyProduct3
            ORDER BY [Name]

              /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/

            RETURN (0)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_uc_rownum3 ON #GetFormularyProduct3 (rownum)

            SELECT rownum,
                ProductKey,
                TypeKey,
                TradeName,
                Active,
                ActiveVendor,
                [Name],
                GenericName,
                VirtualNameCRGenericName,
                NDC,
                ItemID,
                VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
                OncologyOwned,
                DerivedProduct,
                DiscontinuedProduct,
                SequenceNumber,
                IsAuditFavorite,
                GCN,
                DrugGenericName,
                GPI
            FROM #GetFormularyProduct3
            WHERE rownum BETWEEN (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @CurrentPage * @PageSize
            ORDER BY [Name]

              /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/

            RETURN (0)
        END
    END
    ELSE



    IF @Filter = 3  --Show All for IsPracticeFavorite
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE #DiscontinuedAndNotAssigned1 (ProductKey int NOT NULL)

        --These discontinued products are NOT assigned anywhere within this practice; we can remove them from the list
        INSERT INTO #DiscontinuedAndNotAssigned1 (ProductKey)
        SELECT DISTINCT P.ProductKey
        FROM dbo.Product P
        WHERE P.PracticeID = @PracticeID
            AND P.Discontinued = 1
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.Inventory I WHERE I.ProductKey = P.ProductKey AND I.Active = 1)

        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PROD.[Name] ASC) AS rownum,
            PROD.ProductKey,
            PROD.TypeKey,
            PROD.TradeName,
            PROD.Active,
            PV.[Current] AS ActiveVendor,
            PROD.[Name],
            PROD.GenericName,
            PROD.[Name] + char(10) + char(13)
            + dbo.fn_BuildGenericName(PROD.genericname, T.TypeName, PROD.RefrigeratedItem, PROD.Punitsize, PROD.DConversionfactor, UOMDU.Display) AS VirtualNameCRGenericName,
            PROD.NDC,
            PROD.ItemID,
            ISNULL(PROD.ItemID, '''') + char(10) + char(13) + ISNULL(PROD.NDC, '''') AS VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
            PROD.OncologyOwned,
            DerivedProduct,
            PROD.Discontinued AS DiscontinuedProduct,
            PROD.SequenceNumber,
            PROD.IsAuditFavorite,
            PROD.GCN,
            PROD.DrugGenericName,
            PROD.GPI
        INTO #GetFormularyProduct5
        FROM dbo.Product PROD
            INNER JOIN dbo.TypeLookup T ON T.TypeId = PROD.TypeKey
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ProductVendor PV ON PV.ProductKey = PROD.ProductKey
                AND PV.[Current] = 'true'
            LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasureCode UOMDU ON UOMDU.UOMKey = PROD.DUOMKey
        WHERE PROD.Active = 'True'
            AND PROD.TypeKey <> 129
            AND PROD.PracticeID = @PracticeID
            AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT ProductKey FROM #DiscontinuedAndNotAssigned1 X WHERE X.ProductKey = PROD.ProductKey)
            AND PROD.IsPracticeFavorite = 1
        ORDER BY PROD.[Name]


        IF @PageSize = -1 OR @CurrentPage = -1
        BEGIN
            SELECT rownum,
            ProductKey,
            TypeKey,
            TradeName,
            Active,
            ActiveVendor,
            [Name],
            GenericName,
            VirtualNameCRGenericName,
            NDC,
            ItemID,
            VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
            OncologyOwned,
            DerivedProduct,
            DiscontinuedProduct,
            SequenceNumber,
            IsAuditFavorite,
            GCN,
            DrugGenericName,
            GPI
            FROM #GetFormularyProduct5
            ORDER BY [Name]

              /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/

            RETURN (0)
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_uc_rownum3 ON #GetFormularyProduct5 (rownum)

            SELECT rownum,
                ProductKey,
                TypeKey,
                TradeName,
                Active,
                ActiveVendor,
                [Name],
                GenericName,
                VirtualNameCRGenericName,
                NDC,
                ItemID,
                VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
                OncologyOwned,
                DerivedProduct,
                DiscontinuedProduct,
                SequenceNumber,
                IsAuditFavorite,
                GCN,
                DrugGenericName,
                GPI
            FROM #GetFormularyProduct5
            WHERE rownum BETWEEN (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @CurrentPage * @PageSize
            ORDER BY [Name]

              /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/

            RETURN (0)
        END
    END
END
ELSE



IF @formularyType = 2
BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PROD.[Name] ASC) AS rownum,
        PROD.ProductKey,
        PROD.TypeKey,
        PROD.TradeName,
        PROD.Active,
        PV.[Current] as ActiveVendor,
        PROD.[Name],
        PROD.GenericName,
        PROD.[Name] + char(10) + char(13) + dbo.fn_BuildGenericName(PROD.genericname,
            T.TypeName,
            PROD.RefrigeratedItem,
            PROD.Punitsize,
            PROD.DConversionfactor,
            UOMDU.Display) AS VirtualNameCRGenericName,
        PROD.NDC,
        PROD.ItemID,
        ISNULL(PROD.ItemID, '''') + char(10) + char(13) + ISNULL(PROD.NDC, '''') AS VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
        PROD.OncologyOwned AS OncologyOwned,
        DerivedProduct,
        PROD.Discontinued AS DiscontinuedProduct,
        PROD.SequenceNumber,
        PROD.IsAuditFavorite,
        PROD.GCN,
        PROD.DrugGenericName,
        PROD.GPI
    INTO #GetFormularyProduct2
    FROM dbo.Product PROD
        INNER JOIN dbo.TypeLookup T ON T.TypeId = PROD.TypeKey
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Inventory INV ON INV.ProductKey = Prod.ProductKey
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.ProductVendor PV ON PV.ProductKey = PROD.ProductKey
            AND PV.[Current] = 1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.UnitOfMeasureCode UOMDU ON UOMDU.UOMKey = PROD.DUOMKey
    WHERE PROD.Active = 1
        AND PROD.TypeKey <> 129    -- Don''t show kits
        AND PROD.PracticeID IS NULL --@PracticeID
        AND PROD.TenantID = @TenantID
    ORDER BY PROD.[Name]



    IF (@PageSize = -1 OR @CurrentPage = -1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT rownum,
            ProductKey,
            TypeKey,
            TradeName,
            Active,
            ActiveVendor,
            [Name],
            GenericName,
            VirtualNameCRGenericName,
            NDC,
            ItemID,
            VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
            OncologyOwned,
            DerivedProduct,
            DiscontinuedProduct,
            SequenceNumber,
            IsAuditFavorite,
            GCN,
            DrugGenericName,
            GPI
        FROM #GetFormularyProduct2
        ORDER BY [Name]

               /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/
        RETURN (0)
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX idx_uc_rownum2 ON #GetFormularyProduct2 (rownum)

        SELECT rownum,
            ProductKey,
            TypeKey,
            TradeName,
            Active,
            ActiveVendor,
            [Name],
            GenericName,
            VirtualNameCRGenericName,
            NDC,
            ItemID,
            VirtualItemIDcrNDC,
            OncologyOwned,
            DerivedProduct,
            DiscontinuedProduct,
            SequenceNumber,
            IsAuditFavorite,
            GCN,
            DrugGenericName,
            GPI
        FROM #GetFormularyProduct2
        WHERE rownum BETWEEN (@CurrentPage - 1) * @PageSize + 1 AND @CurrentPage * @PageSize
        ORDER BY [Name]

             /*** Log the completion of the stored procedure ***/
              IF @ProcLog_LogCompletion = 1
                  EXEC dbo.ProcLogInsert @ProcName = @ProcLog_ProcName, @ProcLogID = @ProcLog_ProcLogID
              /*********************************************/
        RETURN (0)
    END
END





GO
```

Some proc log records

```
ElapsedTime logdate                 enddate                 Paramlist
0           2014-09-11 19:00:03.300 2014-09-11 19:00:03.920  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
28          2014-09-11 19:01:49.957 2014-09-11 19:02:17.430  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
1           2014-09-11 19:02:48.793 2014-09-11 19:02:49.843  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-11 19:11:43.190 2014-09-11 19:11:43.530  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
1           2014-09-11 19:11:48.907 2014-09-11 19:11:49.257  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-11 19:11:56.210 2014-09-11 19:11:56.483  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-11 19:12:20.190 2014-09-11 19:12:20.523  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-11 19:12:34.580 2014-09-11 19:12:34.920  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-11 19:12:41.063 2014-09-11 19:12:41.323  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-11 19:54:56.287 2014-09-11 19:54:56.490  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-11 19:55:04.347 2014-09-11 19:55:04.520  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-11 19:55:12.013 2014-09-11 19:55:12.170  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
22          2014-09-12 12:02:12.933 2014-09-12 12:02:34.363  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
2           2014-09-12 12:28:15.720 2014-09-12 12:28:17.903  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
3           2014-09-12 12:39:35.203 2014-09-12 12:39:38.130  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
4           2014-09-12 12:40:33.877 2014-09-12 12:40:37.103  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
3           2014-09-12 12:42:20.060 2014-09-12 12:42:23.690  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-12 13:04:13.097 2014-09-12 13:04:13.333  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
0           2014-09-12 13:47:34.050 2014-09-12 13:47:34.270  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
7           2014-09-12 14:37:43.483 2014-09-12 14:37:50.527  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
3           2014-09-12 14:47:34.297 2014-09-12 14:47:37.153  @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1
```

DMV stats ( 2 rows today with different cached time

```
SCHEMA_NAME OBJECT_NAME database_id object_id   type    type_desc   sql_handle  plan_handle cached_time last_execution_time execution_count total_worker_time   last_worker_time    min_worker_time max_worker_time total_physical_reads    last_physical_reads min_physical_reads  max_physical_reads  total_logical_writes    last_logical_writes min_logical_writes  max_logical_writes  total_logical_reads last_logical_reads  min_logical_reads   max_logical_reads   total_elapsed_time  last_elapsed_time   min_elapsed_time    max_elapsed_time
dbo GetFormularyProducts    8   187355932   P   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE    0x030008001CD32A0B70F43801A3A3000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  0x050008001CD32A0B307FD9320200000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2014-09-12 17:43:09.833 2014-09-12 17:43:09.970 1   119014  119014  119014  119014  518 518 518 518 170 170 170 170 48190   48190   48190   48190   588034  588034  588034  588034
dbo GetFormularyProducts    8   187355932   P   SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE    0x030008001CD32A0B70F43801A3A3000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  0x050008001CD32A0BC07C00D00100000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000  2014-09-11 19:00:03.267 2014-09-12 15:59:33.387 63  7253123 111992  93011   310917  44046   518 518 6833    8362    159 0   181 3024242 47980   47968   48193   367605152   3551205 158005  27479580
```

At 2014-09-12 17:43:09.970 -- sproc cached time,  proc log record was 
        LogDate EndDate ProcName    ParamList
        2014-09-12 17:43:09.973 2014-09-12 17:43:10.557 GetFormularyProducts     @FormularyType = 2 @PracticeID = NULL @Filter = 2 @PageSize = -1

Comment: What does the stored procedure look like?  Some code would be helpful.  Are you passing in a parameter?  Without more details we would be guessing. Sounds like parameter sniffing but...you need to provide a lot more details.

Comment: That table is unreadable as the column headers are not aligned. Please consider setting results to text and rerunning the query or using http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html

Comment: Could be server resources as well...is this on a test server, or do you have a lot of other transactions on the fly at any given time?

Comment: There're way too many things this could be for us to help you without a lot more information. Starting with the table schema and the code for at least one of the procedures.

Comment: I agree 1000% percent with @bluefeet. This sounds like parameter sniffing. Take a look here and make sure you look at parts 2 and 3. http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2007/11/27/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: while you're (inevitably) editing the question, please post the ***actual*** query plan (link to dropbox/gist.github/answers.sqlperformance.com), the ddl, the output of `dbcc show_statistics` for the column(s) upon which you're filtering, the values that you're using - better yet ... post both of the queries! otherwise, we have no idea. i'd be tempted to blame it on the most recent x-class solar flare, given the information at hand.

Comment: As pointed out by most above comments, it can be the stored procedure code. We have a vendor application that we cannot modify any of the stored procedures. Looking at performance we found `WHERE FirstName like @FirstName and LastName like @LastName`. If @FirstName = 'someFirstname%' and @LastName = 'SomeLastName%' then it performs well but user search criteria allows users to search by @FirstName = `%Firstname%` and @LastName = `%Lastname%` which performance suffers as it cannot use index seek and have to use index scan.

Comment: @bluefeet, The sproc can have different parameters.  I just started logging the proc to see if it is parameter sniffing.  thanks

Comment: @swasheck, I cannot upload dbcc show_stats or execution plan.  There is a limit of number of chars.  Let me know if you are interested in them and I can email them.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone who looked at my question.  I have changed the sproc to disable parameter sniffing by using local variables.  I will monitor next week to see if the issue clears.

Thank you all very much.